# Python: Collapsing arrays of arrays into each other without for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have multiple NxN 2D arrays stored into a list in Python 3. I want to collapse all the arrays into 1 array, with the same dimensions NxN, but such that each element of this new array contains a 1xN array of the corresponding values from the original arrays.

To give you some more context, each array in this list corresponds to the set of values at a given time. For each new time point, I am storing the updated version of that array into the list. Once that's done, I want to compute the standard deviation of the values at each (i,j) element in the array.

I tried using a for loop, but it takes far too long for my simulations because this is a set of 100,000 arrays. I was wondering if there were any numpy or vectorized functions that can help me perform this operation more efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can have lists as numpy array elements for example; do you mean add an extra dimension to the array so that it becomes a 3d array?

Comment: In particular, have a look at `numpy.stack` - https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html

Comment: For example, if `x` and `y` are both 3x3 numpy arrays, then `numpy.stack([x, y])` would be a 2x3x3 array, or `numpy.stack([x,y], axis=2)` would be a 3x3x2 array (axis defaults to 0).

Comment: @alaniwi you can have lists as numpy array elements. In fact you can have any object stored as numpy elements.

Comment: @Ehsan Interesting, I didn't know that. (Not using a machine with working numpy under python 3 just now, I tried it on a Python 2.7 installation and got `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.) But does it serve any useful purpose in this case having a list at every element (all the same length) compared to having an array with an extra dimension? I suspect not.

Comment: @alaniwi it is usually not advised to have a list of arrays. But in this case, I can see why. If you have a time series changing, appending to list is faster than appending to an array. I would personally store it similarly in to a list and then stack them into a single array. But if you have everything from the get go, a single array is preferred as you mentioned.

Comment: @Ehsan It wasn't so much the input list of arrays I was referring to (the OP's input), but their desired output (an array in which every element is a list), which I didn't realise was even possible. You seem to be saying that it is in principle possible; however, the fact that you have now posted an answer using `numpy.stack` suggests that even so, you agree with me that it wouldn't be an efficient solution.

Comment: @alaniwi Actually, only the original input list of arrays is a list. The elements in the collapsed array are themselves an array with dimensions 1xN. I have edited the word 'list' in my opening paragraph to reflect this now. Apologies and thanks!

Comment: @Ferreroire please see if the posted solution resolves your issue. If not, please elaborate in the comment and I would edit accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say `l` is your list of arrays. You need to get std of corresponding elements of those arrays into a single array:

```
std_l = np.std(np.stack(l),axis=0)
```